# Binding Generic class object in Google guice

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

I have the following config file..

```
*.*.HM.Evaluation.Types = {
   "key1" = "value1";
   "key2" = "value2";
   "key3" = "value3";
};
```

I have the following constructor injection...

```
@Inject
public myConstuctor(@NonNull @Named("HM.Evaluation.Types") final Map<String , String> myMap) { ... }
```

This Works when I run my code using

```
Properties myProperties = new Properties().load(new FileReader("myConfig.properties"));
Names.BindProperties(Binder() , myProperties);
```

When I test my code using JUnits, I am not able to bind a

```
Map< String,String> class
```

The following code

```
Injector injector = Guice.CreateInjector((AbstractModule) -> {
bind(Map.class)
    .annotatedWith(Names.named("HM.Evaluation.Types")).toInstance(DUMMP_MAP);
});
```

gives me the following a google guice error

> no implementation for java.lang.map< string , string> is found for the value Named(value = "HM.Evaluation.Types")

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can bind generics

Using a provider method (personal favorite)

```
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  ...
  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @Named("HM.Evaluation.Types")
  Map<String,String> provideDummpMap() {
    return DUMMP_MAP;
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can use `TypeLiteral`:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Map<String,String>>(){})
  .annotatedWith(Names.named("HM.Evaluation.Types"))
  .toInstance(DUMMP_MAP);
```

Comment: After searching I found another solution, using MapBinders